# How to change placeholder of kendo multiselect widget by css

Tags: css, kendo-ui, placeholder, multi-select

How to change placeholder of kendo multiselect widget by css rules?

```
.k-multiselect-wrap > .k-input {
   color: #f02c0c; /* specify the default input color */
   content: "HOME";
}
```

This rule doesn't work.
Change the color, but not the content.

Comment: they are working solutions, but they do not exactly respond to my problem.

Comment: I would like to find a solution with the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a css solution you can use `:before` pseudo class.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select").kendoMultiSelect();
});

//k-widget k-multiselect k-header k-multiselect-clearable
```

```css
.select-parent .k-multiselect-wrap ul {
  position: relative;
}

.select-parent .k-multiselect-wrap ul:before {
  content: "Required users...";
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="k-content select-parent">
  <select id="select" multiple="multiple">
    <option>k-content 1</option>
    <option>k-content 2</option>
    <option>k-content 3</option>
    <option>k-content 4</option>
    <option>k-content 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: This solution doesn't create the dropdown and the submit for the validation of the form is missing

Comment: @Federico your question was about creating the placeholder using css....so where comes the validation part..?....And its working fine when I click on the blue `Run code snippet` button above....

Comment: On the validator you're right. It's one more thing that's in my example.
Pretend you did not ask for it.
However, the snippet does not work for me.This is the error: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoMultiSelect is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 36,
  "colno": 16
}

Answer (score 2):

> [*The content CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

From the kendo multi-select widget [**Reference Link**](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index), I found that you can change the placeholder of the multi-select by using `data-placeholder`

```
<select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="HOME">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CSS you should do it using placeholder.

You can do it from HTML using `data-placeholder` attribute on `select`

```
<select id="optional" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Optional Users">
```

or you can do in JavaScript the initialization of the MultiSelect.

```
var optional = $("#optional").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose: false,
    placeholder:"Optional Users..."
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "Required Users...",
    dataSource: [
      "Steven White",
      "Nancy King",
      "Nancy Davolio",
      "Robert Davolio",
      "Michael Leverling",
      "Andrew Callahan",
      "Michael Suyama",
      "Anne King",
      "Laura Peacock",
      "Robert Fuller",
      "Janet White",
      "Nancy Leverling",
      "Robert Buchanan",
      "Margaret Buchanan",
      "Andrew Fuller",
      "Anne Davolio",
      "Andrew Suyama",
      "Nige Buchanan",
      "Laura Fuller"
    ]
  }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

  var optional = $("#optional").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "Optional Users..."
  }).data("kendoMultiSelect");


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo-section k-content">
  <h2>Invite Requried</h2>
  <select id="required" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
  <h2>Invite Attendees</h2>
  <label for="optional">Optional</label>
  <select id="optional" multiple="multiple">
      <option>Steven White</option>
      <option>Nancy King</option>
      <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
      <option>Robert Davolio</option>
      <option>Michael Leverling</option>
      <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
      <option>Michael Suyama</option>
      <option>Anne King</option>
      <option>Laura Peacock</option>
      <option>Robert Fuller</option>
      <option>Janet White</option>
      <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
      <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
      <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
      <option>Andrew Fuller</option>
      <option>Anne Davolio</option>
      <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
      <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
      <option>Laura Fuller</option>
  </select>
</div>
```